# Problem with Row size - Not returning value when length is full (100 char)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a database in SQL Server. In this database I have a column `VARCHAR[100]` named Name. The problem is when I try to return this value in PHP and this column has all their characters (100), PHP returns me:

> String data, right truncation

but if I remove the last 3-4 characters of the string, PHP returns it without problem.

Why is happening this and how can I solve it? I have to remove the last characters of all strings or there is a way to do it automatically?

Comment: You need to show your PHP code which accesses this data - there is a mismatch there somewhere.

Comment: What are the versions of `PHP Driver for SQL Server`, `SQL Server` and `PHP`?

Comment: Hello, im using a simple loop to get all rows, im not printing anything, my code now is this:

`$sql10 = "SELECT * FROM Articles";
$count=0;
$stmt10 = sqlsrv_query( $conn2, $sql10 ,array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'keyset' ));
echo "<h3>Number of articles: ".sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt10 )."</h3>";
while( $row10 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt10, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $count++;
    echo $count;
}`

Comment: The SQLSRV Version is 10.50.6220.0, php version is 7.4.0

Comment: Sorry, the PHP Driver for SQL is the ODBC Driver 17 Version

Comment: @josesd please [edit] your clarifications directly into your question.

Comment: @josesd Can you post the exact value of the `Name` column for the row, that generates this error? Thanks.

Comment: Of course, they are books in Spanish, for example: "Módulo alimentación y nutrición familiar, técnico en atención sociosanitaria, formación profesional"
This book has 99 char and returns error, but if I remove the last 2-3 char the "truncate error" disappears, can't understand why